# Registration form gives error when passed as a component to a Route

Tags: reactjs

I have a file called `Register.js` containing ant design's registration form which when I pass to a Route in `App.js` gives me an error as below:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:undefined.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `RegistrationForm`.
```

A slightly modified [Register.js](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-grass-p8c3f). The modification is that instead of rendering it directly, I am exporting it using `export default WrappedRegistrationForm;`

I am importing and then using it in the Route as follows in `App.js`:

```js
import WrappedRegistrationForm from './components/Onboard';

<Route                                           
   exact                                             
   path="/register"                                          
   component={WrappedRegistrationForm}/>
```

Here `Onboard` is a folder inside `components` containing `Register.js` and `index.js`.

```
Onboard/
    Register.js
    index.js
```

Where the index.js file simply imports the component from `Register.js` and exports it.

`Onboard/index.js`

```js
import WrappedRegistrationForm from './Register';

export default WrappedRegistrationForm;
```

How do I successfully render `Register.js` on visiting the route `/register`.

Comment: try changing Onboard/index.js to export WrappedRegistrationForm  from './Register';

Comment: if that doesn't work please paste here the content of './Register'

Comment: Are you sure that you are not forgetting or doing wrong about something import/export? It works [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-moon-dn2ip)

Comment: That didn't work. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BVhs8bwbc8/) is the exact `Register.js`

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for the snippet. I have double checked my code, but still I can't see where I am going wrong.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by saying "didn't work" but I pasted the same code you gave above to the sandbox and it still works for me. Try to create a sandbox please.